# Как сложить элементы с одинаковым индексом у нескольких списков Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сложить элементы с одинаковым индексом у нескольких списков в Python?

Например, есть списки:
`a = ['1', '2'], b =['3', '4'], c =['5', '6']`

На выходе нужно получить `d = ['9', '12']`

И если дан такой список `a = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]`

Спасибо!

Comment: `'1'+'3'+'5' == '135'`, а не `'9'`.

Comment: мне именно сумму чисел нужно

Comment: Но у вас в списках строки. В результате тоже список строк.

Comment: Понял, а из такого как получить `a = [1, 2], b = [3, 4], c = [5, 6]` такое `d = [9, 12]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```py
a, b, c = [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]
zip_obj = zip(a,b,c) # "Сшиваем" списки, получаем ((1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6))
map_obj = map(sum, zip_obj) # Суммируем элементы в каждом подсписке
result = list(map_obj) # Преобразовываем в list
```

Если коротко:

```py
a, b, c = [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]
result = list(map(sum, zip(a, b, c)))
```

Comment: спасибо большое!)

Comment: Есть галочка, если ответ помог.

Comment: да ее просто только через 3 минуты можно поставить после ответа

Comment: извините, еще один вопрос, как быть если список дан вот в таком виде: `a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` Как по такому же принципу получить список `[9, 12]`

Comment: изменил вопрос.

Comment: `result = list(map(sum, zip(*a)))`. Вопрос лучше верните обратно, ибо ответ был дан именно на него.

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [5, 6]

res = np.array([a,b,c]).sum(axis=0).tolist()
print(res)
```

результат:

```
[9, 12]
```

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```
a = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
res = []
for i in range(len(a[0])):
    k = sum([int(elem[i]) for elem in a])
    res.append(str(k))
print(res)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 5]
c = [124, -8]

result = [0]*len(a)
for sublist in [a, b, c]:
    for i in range(len(sublist)):
        result[i] += sublist[i]
```